# Swapping Keys Still Introduces Fresh DOM Element

Tags: reactjs

In [this](https://3bnbe2.csb.app/) example, the key of the two elements are swapped, so in theory, there should be a transition on both elements, as they change opacity.  But apparently, React only keeps one element, and replaces the other by a fresh one.  Is this a bug or do I miss something about the semantics of the `key` property?

[Here](https://dtgoj8.csb.app/) is a version where I use an effect for the updates, to illustrate what I wanted to achive.  I wonder if this is nicer anyway, since I don't have the `oldIndex` state.

JSX:

```
export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [oldIndex, setOldIndex] = useState();
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(0);
  const clickHandler = useCallback(
    (d) =>
      function () {
        setOldIndex(index);
        setIndex(index + d);
        setToggle(1 - toggle);
      },
    [index, toggle]
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clickHandler(-1)}>Decrease</button>
      <button onClick={clickHandler(1)}>Increase</button>
      <h1 className="active" key={1 - toggle}>
        {index}
      </h1>
      <h1 className="inactive" key={toggle}>
        {oldIndex}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 2000ms;
}
h1.inactive {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Adding even more elements makes it even weirder https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-shockley-iokidc?file=/src/App.jsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a React issue, it's a DOM issue. There is no way in the DOM API to swap two nodes, the only way to do it is to remove one of them and then insert it again at a different place, so that's what React is forced to do.

You need to find a different way to do it, for instance by swapping the classes and the contents instead of trying to swap the elements.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!  Will use an effect instead...